# Configure Amazon Cloudfront Compression

Tags: amazon-web-services, compression, amazon-cloudfront

The current minimum threshold file size needs to be 1KB to enable Gzip compression in AWS Cloudfront.  I would like to reduce the minimum file size requirement for compression from 1KB to 200B.  How can I configure the same?

Comment: Why do you think 1MB?  It's 1**K**B. [*"CloudFront compresses files that are between 1,000 bytes and 10,000,000 bytes in size."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html)

Comment: You are right.  Corrected.  My use case will still hold true for a threshold of 1KB.  My current payload of ~ 900B is taking 700ms through the wire.  Most of the search result functionalities are able to send the same data gzipped over to the client @ ~300B in 300ms

Comment: Fundamentally, though, the problem is that 900B should not take 700ms, as that is a throughput of only about 10 kilobits per second.  Even if we assume high round trip times, that's still not reasonable. Something in your stack is too slow.  For comparison, I just checked a site of mine that generates a dynamic, uncompressed response, with gzip and caching *disabled* in CloudFront.  For a 1.5KB response, TTFB is 57ms, content download is 6ms.  I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Interesting... I will deep dive.  Is your server and client co-located.  My server is in CA and my client is in Luxembourg.  When done locally, it takes ~ 200-300ms

Answer (score 1):

At the moment gzip file size is not configurable in AWS CloudFront and only enabled for certain [file types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types).

According to the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html), in rare cases, when a CloudFront edge location is unusually busy, some files might not be compressed.